# Backend and frontend for android

Tags: java, android, database

I am developing an android app using java language in frontend.I want to make use of server database for storing the data and later i will retrieve that data in my app.
Which backend language can be used for this.I am not good in php,but good in java.

My question is can java swings be used as backend.Kindly help

I am also looking for a good example which has android(with java language) as frontend and mysql database and java as backend.Kindly provide any links which has a combination of android,java and Mysql database.

Comment: can anyone help me with some idea.I do not know how exactly to work on this.I am new to this android and database

Comment: You really need to do your research first man.

Comment: I am completely getting confused with working between android as frontend and database as backend.

Comment: I want to store some list of data in the database and want to retrieve and print it in the android app but i want to make use of server for later updation of list. I am knowing how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Swing is a GUI widget toolkit for Java, how comes to be backend ? what you need exactly is building simple webservice something like API with gson as content format. on backend you can use whatever you want.if you are familiar with Java. you can build your web server application on Tomcat. or simply you can just make servlets that reacts to CRUD operations.
don't forget to secure access by applying authentication like user/password or client credentials.
so briefly what you need to **learn how to**:

1- build a web application via Java web (servlet/JSP)

2- build a module that does CRUD operations (create, read, update and delete) on database on server.

Setting separated endpoints for each type of operation is recommended. i.e.:

post: http://apipas.com/projectName/v1/create (create new record)

get: http://apipas.com/projectName/v1/get&id=111 (get data from server)

post: http://apipas.com/projectName/v1/update (update existing data on server)

....

check this tutorial : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/
it's a good guide how to build web app and how to access DB.

3- build a module on android that communicate with web app to make operations on DB on server. generally you are going to use HTTP protocol.

Check this to know how to deal with http communication on android: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Network/HttpGetandHttpPost.htm

---

Develop a web service API ( with GSON ) is more advanced level ... think about it if you are going to build serious production project.

Good luck,'.